# How can I list all documents of a subcollection using FirestoreUI?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to list all documents of a certain subcollection using FirestoreUI but it does not work, the thing is that the reyclerView does not show anything and yet there are documents in the subcollection.
Any help

```
    val ref=firebaseFirestore.collection("Shops")
        .document(linkOfthisShop).collection("Adverts")
    val query:Query=ref

    val options= FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<AdvertModel>()
        .setQuery(query, AdvertModel::class.java)
        .build()
    adapter=AdvertAdapter(options)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.adapter=adapter
```

this is my adapter:

class AdvertAdapter( options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions
) : FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<AdvertModel, AdvertAdapter.ViewHolder>(options) {

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int
):ViewHolder {
   val layout=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
       .inflate(R.layout.advert_layout_shop_details,parent,false)

    return ViewHolder(layout)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(layout: ViewHolder, p1: Int, model: AdvertModel) {

    layout.nameOfTheAd!!.text=model.nameOfAd
    layout.priceOfAd!!.text=model.price
    Picasso.get().load(model.image1).into(layout.image)

}




class ViewHolder( view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    var image:ImageView?=null
    var nameOfTheAd:TextView?=null
    var priceOfAd:TextView?=null


    init {

        image=view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_shops_details_advert)
        nameOfTheAd=view.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopsDetailsNameOfAd)
        priceOfAd=view.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopsDetailsPriceOfAd)



    }
}
```

}

this is the model
package com.iliassouabdillahmrijou.firestore.shops

class AdvertModel() {

```
var image1:String?= null
var image2:String?= null
var image3:String?= null
var nameOfAd:String?= null
var descriptionOfAd:String?= null
var price:String?= null

constructor(image1:String,image2:String,image3:String,
            nameOfAd:String, descriptionOfAd:String, price:String) : this() {
    this.image1=image1
    this.image2=image2
    this.image3=image3
    this.nameOfAd=nameOfAd
    this.descriptionOfAd=descriptionOfAd
    this.price=price


}
```

}

Comment: It's not possible to list subcollections of a collection using Android APIs for Firestore.  Your query is trying to list all documents within a subcollection.

Comment: Sorry I want to list all documents of a subcollection  not all subcollections

Comment: OK, what's wrong with the code you've written?  Please edit the question to explain what's not working the way you expect.